# Should every PHP query have an exception, or just a general error, or neither

Tags: php

I am working with Databases, to update, delete, or insert. At the moment I am only doing some errors on some. Should I use an exception on EVERY database query I run, or just a general error?

Let me visual show you.

**Exception**

```
$query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(1)");
$result = $query->execute();
try{
   if(!result): throw new exception(""); else: //success  endif;
}
```

**Or**

```
$query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(1)");
$result = $query->execute();
if(!$result): return 0; else:  //success  endif;
```

Then (for my case an MVC, check if that function is == 0 then redirect to an error page

**Or no error notifications:**

```
$query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(1)");
$result = $query->execute();
```

Which one of these is recommended, or not recommended if any?

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO? If you use PDO, you can tell it to throw exceptions automatically.

Comment: It's the `execute()` that is likely to throw an exception (if you configure it that way) but it's outside the `try` in your first example.

Comment: PDO... how do I accomplish that?

Comment: [To turn on PDO exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pdo+exception+errmode) /cc @Barmar.

Comment: For full documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Is PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION recommended for a live website?

Comment: @johnsmith, theres no reason not to use it for a live site. You just need to adapt you method of error handling to deal with exceptions, which IMO is easier anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something can go wrong, and that would affect something you find important, you should act on the error.

This doesn't always mean producing an error page. You would only do that if the error has an effect on the visitor of your site. For instance, when a registration is submitted, but cannot be entered into the database:

> "Sorry, we have a technical problem, your registration can, at the
>   moment, not be accepted. An email with your details has been sent to
>   to us. Will we contact you soon.".

There are other errors that do not need feedback like this, but which you would like to know about. For instance when you count how often a page is visited. Make a log, send a email, or something similar, but do not bother your visitor with error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The second case: `if(!$result): return false;`
is important to know in order to update your db, instead of interrupting the code. 
Errors are useful at the development stage.
This is a case that sth else will happen.